# Config-dependent assembly reference

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I have an assembly generated **from DSL**, and I need to make a reference to it from my project.

However, I'd like to have reference to Debug assembly from Debug project config, and to Release from Release.

Is it possible to achieve?

Comment: This works automatically if both projects are in the same solution.

Comment: This assembly is generated from DSL, by external compiler. Read before posting.

Comment: "external compiler" is something that only appeared in your reply comment, so I don't see that John was wrong in his reply - given that the VS SDK DSL tools integrate well with VS and you would be able to have a DSL based project and a "normal" project in the same solution. So perhaps you need to add more detail about your DSL tool/compiler into your question. How do you want your build process to work if the DSL build is out of date, for instance?

Comment: I wrote about referenced assembly, not referenced project. That's big difference. And stop point begging, please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, so what I've found... assembly reference can be edited manually in the project file, putting $(Configuration) instead of "Debug"/"Release" path part. It works without problems.

Answer (score 0):

Well, add assembly generation from DSL as a build event - that way, you can generate correct version (debug/release) of assembly. Configuration Name is available as macro [`$(ConfigurationName)`]. Also, you have to be smart in such command line to skip assembly generation if its already generated and DSL has not been modified - it means you need to have different intermediate target location based on configuration and then copy from that location to some other main location (if file is modified). This other location is the one from where you will reference the assembly in your project.

Comment: In this case, build after switching config will create project with wrong version of generated assembly. Can't say I like this solution very much, but it should work if nothing better is available.

Comment: @user536232, I had suggested to create generated assembly in config specific folder (e.g. Obj\Debug\dsl.dll, Obj\Release\dsl.dll) and then copy it to say bin folder from where it will be referenced. So switching config shouldn't matter because you will always copy assembly from the that particular config folder.